# Evince without restrictions on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, pdf, latex, evince, visualization

I love to use Evince, is one of the best software for visualize a lot of things, including pdfs. I use it many times with LaTeX. Also, before I could select text and copy it, but now, with Ubuntu 14.04 it's impossible!!!

I don't know why or what happen, but the version available by default with Ubuntu 14.04 is very restricted, limited. The versión is the 3.10.3 but if I download it from the web (in Windows e.g.) I can customize it easily and use it as before. Why not in Ubuntu?

In a nutshell: Do you know how can I use Evince as before? Should I uninstall it and download it from outside? How?

Comment: Here here. Evince has been gutted and rendered essentially useless.

Comment: @MarkWayne I don't understand, who decided what was useless?

Comment: Anyway -- is there a way to revert to the version that was associated with 12.04 LTS?

Comment: I use Evince 3.10.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 and am able to select and copy text. Isn't it something with the file?

Answer (score 1):

You might wish to try [Atril](https://github.com/mate-desktop/atril), the Evince fork included with Mate. It seems to include all the original features that where there before the Gnome folk decided to "kill the desktop".

You need to add the Mate PPA before installing:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/trusty-mate
sudo apt-get install atril
```

Comment: Pfffffffff I had troubles to add the ppa of Mate to my Ubuntu, now I have a mess with a lot of broken dependences and without Evince well installed. Is not a problem with an specific file as you asked before in the comment, is the same problem in three different machines where I installed Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits with several files, all the files I open.

Comment: Can you detail the problems you had adding the Mate PPA?

Comment: Whe I try to update or install something new, the terminal says: 

`W: Imposible obtener http://repo.mate-desktop.org/archive/1.8/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found`

`W: Imposible obtener http://repo.mate-desktop.org/archive/1.8/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found`

`W: Imposible obtener http://repo.mate-desktop.org/archive/1.8/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found`

`E: Algunos archivos de índice fallaron al descargar. Se han ignorado, o se han utilizado unos antiguos en su lugar`